# I WouldUpdate my angular Js view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I get an application and when I modify my bd, view Angular does not change.
I tried using  `$scope.$apply()`.
If you can help me, thanks a lot !!

```js
  $scope.modifyTask = function(id){
    todoService.modifyTodos(id);
  }
```

```html
<i class="ion-android-checkbox-outline-blank caseACocher" ng-click="modifyTask(data.id)">
```

By cons, if I reload the page , it's ok. But I would not need to reload the page

Comment: Could you make a working snippet please?

Comment: $scope.apply should be called automatically from the $watch/$digest cycle. 

Do you change your data in the controller? it seems like you change something in a factory. 

btw we need more code of the controller and the view

Comment: I click on the box and I update my BD.

Comment: Can you post the code of `modifyTodos()`?

Answer (score 0):

There are many things that could be happening. Two things off the top of my head are:

1. You could be returning a `promise` from `todoService` and not resolving it.
2. `id` might be getting changed outside the scope, thereby `$scope.apply` will need to be invoked, like you said
3. You don't seem to be binding anything to `$scope.id`. You'll need to bind the DOM element to scope in order for it to reflect on your view